Efficently Updating Large Datasets in EF Core
I am looking to improve on the updating performance of data sets and seeking insights.
I have a set of 2000 rows of data in table TestResults, when new datset is made available all of the 2000 rows of data have to be updated with their respective values, in this case ratingDate and rating.
// The class
public class TestResults 
{
    //...other properties
    public int Rating {get;set}
    public DateTime RatingDate {get;set;}
    //...other properties
}

// updating with latest data
foreach(var item in updatedTestResults) 
{
    context.TestResults
           .Where(x => x.Id == item.Id)
           .ExecuteUpdate(setters => setters
                 .SetProperty(b => b.RatingDate, item.RatingDate)
                 .SetProperty(b => b.Rating, item.Rating));
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

My understanding is that this will generate a SQL update request for each entry (approximately 2000 of them).
Is there a better way, a more efficient way to do the update?

Yes, but with third party extensions, CreateTempTable, BulkCopy in that table, execute update by join to this table. Will add sample if requested.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv open to ideas on how others have tackled this challenge

You can use extension linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore, note that I'm one of the creators.
using var db = context.CreateLinqToDBConnection();

var simplifiedData = updatedTestResults.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.RatingDate, x.Rating });

// create temporary table
using var tempTable = await db.CreateTempTableAsync(simplifiedData, tableName: "tempTestResults");

// join temporary table with table which should be updated
var updateQuery =
    from tr in context.TestResults
    join t in tempTable on tr.Id equals t.Id
    select new { tr, t };

// execute Update query
await updateQuery
    .Set(x => x.tr.RatingDate, x => x.t.RatingDate)
    .Set(x => x.tr.Rating, x => x.t.Rating)
    .UpdateAsync();


Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv will explore this option

Note that with this extension you can use Merge, which will allow Upsert. Usually people forget to mention that something should be updated and something inserted or even deleted.
